# How to add a char to a String recursively?

Tags: java, string, recursion

I'm trying to write a method that inserts a given char c into a String s at a position i (these are all given as parameters). For example, given parameters of 'z', 3, and "bbbb", it should return "bbbzb". Of course, I could do:

```
return s.substring(0, i) + c + s.substring(i + 1);
```

But the catch is, it must be recursive. The code that I came up with is as follows:

```
    public static String insertInto(char c, int i, String s) {
    return insertIntoHelper(c, i, s, 0);
}

public static String insertIntoHelper(char c, int i, String s, int index) {
    if (s == null || s.equals("")) {
        return "";
    }
    if (index == i) {
        return c + insertIntoHelper(c, i, s, index++);
    } else {
        return s.substring(0, 1) + insertIntoHelper(c, i, s.substring(1), index++);
    }
}
```

The logic here being that if the index is less than i, return the first letter, then the rest of the string, or if the index is equal to it, add the character, etc. There must be a hole in my logic somewhere, because it is not working, and I even get an error when I set the index to 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely there must be other problems you can test that use recursion in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Note that you can't insert anything into a String, recursively or not.  A String is immutable, so you must create new Strings if you want to "insert" anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is using the postfix increment in the recursive calls.

```
}                                        //   |
if (index == i) {                        //   v
    return c + insertIntoHelper(c, i, s, index++);                    //   |
} else {                                                              //   v
    return s.substring(0, 1) + insertIntoHelper(c, i, s.substring(1), index++);
}
```

The postfix increment 'returns' the int value from before the increment happens ([JLS 15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)). So use a regular `+ 1`.

```
if (index == i) {
    return c + insertIntoHelper(c, i, s, index + 1);
} else {
    return s.substring(0, 1) + insertIntoHelper(c, i, s.substring(1), index + 1);
}
```

That works though I agree with others that there are other problems better suited to recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static String insertInto(char c, int i, String s) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return c+s;
    }
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    return s.charAt(0) + insertInto(c,i-1,s.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but the code doesn't compile. `isEmpty(s)` and `insert`. Personally I wouldn't down vote for that since otherwise the code works.